is this a novel approach to visualization of qubits?
I am currently working on my Bachelor's Thesis and would love to hear your opinions about my project.
The idea is to visualize the Binary parts of complex qubit states.
White lines represent binary 0, black lines binary 1
Here is an example of the Bell State:

You can also see how the state vector changes after each gate

This quantum Teleportation shows that the bottom qubit is 1 after measurement because the top qubit is 1 as input:

I also implemented Grover and Shor. If you want to try the program, you can find it here: https://github.com/PichlerMathias/QuantumVisualizationBuild.
I think this project could help beginners to understand quantum computing.
Do you think this program could be useful? Have you seen a visualization like this before?
Thanks for your opinions in advance!

I would refer you to check platform.classiq.io for visualization of circuit + execution results - showing the interpretation of the number, and the phase in color when running Statevector simulator

I think, for beginners, the duplication of the gates across the different states will be a nasty conceptual hurdle for this particular representation. Physically, a CNOT gate is done the same way regardless of whether the control qubit is |0> or |1> or |0>+|1> (e.g. you send the same microwave pulse), but in this drawing those situations look very different. You'd need to do user testing to know for sure what works; I have my doubts.
The 3d models look good, but aren't really taking advantage of having an extra direction. These particular examples would be clearer if flattened into 2d.

I support this, but must caution: any representation will have to grow exponentially with the number of qubits - there are an exponentially growing number of degrees of freedom!
